# How to properly encode an Excel file in base64 for upload via an API

Tags: r, api, shiny, base64, attachment

I am trying to upload an Excel as an attachment via an API call that requires a base64 encoded version of the Excel file.  The file is uploaded successfully via the API, but when downloaded Excel shows a message that the file is corrupted and cannot be opened.

I have tried various different tweaks to the payload output. I am following exactly what the API reference documentation asks for and the file is uploading successfully. I expect that the file should be able to be downloaded and opened after upload, but am getting a corrupted file. Here is the code that successfully uploads the file, but does not seem to be properly encoding the file:

Here is my existing code that successfully uploads the file. The Payload structure is based on the API documentation:

```
     url <- <api_url>
              
     # Read the contents of the Excel file as a raw object
     excel_file_raw <- readBin(excel_file_path, what = "raw", n =file.info(excel_file_path)$size)
              
     # Encode the Excel file as a base64 string
     file_64_content <- base64enc::dataURI(excel_file_raw,paste0("application/vnd.openxmlformats-     officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;name=",file_name), encoding = "base64")
              
      # Define boundary string
      boundary_string <- "-----boundary"
              
      # Create payload
     payload <- paste0("--", boundary_string,
               "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"", file_name, "\"",
               "\r\n\r\n",file_64_content,
               "\r\n--", boundary_string,
               "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"parent\"",
               "\r\n\r\n", task_id,
               "\r\n--", boundary_string,
               "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"resource_subtype\"",
               "\r\n\r\nattachment",
               "\r\n--", boundary_string, "--\r\n")

     # Send POST request
     response <- httr::POST(url,
                     body = payload,
                     add_headers('authorization' = paste0("Bearer ", api_token),
                     'content-type' = paste0("multipart/form-data; boundary=", boundary_string),
                     'accept' = 'application/json'),
                     encode = "multipart")

    # Check API response
    content(response, "text")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read the file. You can do:

```r
dataURI(file = path_to_xlsx_file, mime = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Unfortunately, the same thing is happening. One thing I tried is editing the corrupted file after download and changing the extension from xlsx to xls. When I do this I can open the file an the contents of the file are the data attribute in the payload which is the URI value with the file as a base 64 string. So seems like the string is not being interpreted correctly as a file or is not being decoded properly.

Comment: @ncmc100 I don't know... maybe you have to remove the "prefix" of the base64 string? (until the semi-colon).